# Creating Confirm Email Field that Matches Email Field

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is there a way to create a matching email address field? I want to create a "confirm email" field to ensure the user is correctly inputting his/her email. I'm using the form composer as well, so I'm hoping there's an easy way to set this up versus having to manually create a form template and manually create each form field. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is the 'matching_fields' parameter which allows you to do just that. See the documentation for details: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/

Comment: Is there a way to do this through the form composer? I have a lot of fields, so I don't want to have to code in all the fields manually just to do this.I tried to create a conditional, but the label and fields don't publish correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to add a matching field requirement when using the Freeform Composer, unless you have a situation where:

1. you know the exact names of the fields that would need to match, which you could hard-code in a custom Composer Template, or
2. you know that for your form, all field of a specific fieldtype (eg. all text inputs) would *all* require a matching field, which in this case you would also need to create a custom Composer Template.

You will also need the [`matching_fields=""` parameter](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#matching_fields).

**For 1**, you would create a custom Composer Template (either through the CP or by using {exp:freeform:composer} as a tag pair, [see documentation](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/composer/)), and add something like the following where appropriate:

```
...
{if:else} {!-- snippet code from default Composer Template --}
    {if composer:field_name == "email"}
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="email_confirm" value="" />
    {if:else}
        <p>{composer:field_output}</p>
    {/if}
{/if}
```

As you can see, you would need to know the name of the field beforehand. It's not automagic.

**For 2**, the approach is similar, but using `{composer:field_type}` instead of `{composer:field_type}`

Of course both approaches are not "set and forget" ways of adding this functionality when using Composer. I recommend submitting this as a **Feature Request** under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on:

http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

Comment: I have a situation like the first one. I'm just trying to match the email address. I tried to do what you said, but I can't get it to work. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I've uploaded a screenshot of the section of the code.

[link]http://tinyurl.com/kym22k7

Comment: Your conditional is in the `nonfield_captcha` conditional (which is for the captcha field), i.e. it's in the wrong place. It should be inside `{if:else}<p>{composer:field_output}</p>{/if}`

Comment: Okay, I got it to sort of work. But the problem is that I can't get the formatting to look right and the labels don't show. This is how it's looking (I want the label to say "Confirm Email" above the confirm email field). http://tinyurl.com/nd9suzh

I tried to create a conditional so that when the field name email shows, I can just manually the email and confirm email label and fields to show, but I don't know how to stop the email field from outputting in the composer:field_output. Is this even the way to go about it?